# I have to write query based on cases can i write like this

Tags: oracle

```
    SELECT   DISTINCT  AD_MA_CODE,AD_PA_CODE,AD_EN_CODE_PSV,AD_CODE,
    CASE  WHEN AD_EN_CODE_PSV = ID_EN_CODE_PSV AND  AD_CODE = ID_AD_CODE THEN '1' 
     WHEN AD_CODE_POSTAL=ZL_CODE_POSTAL AND AD_VILLE=ZL_VILLE THEN AD_ADR_DEFAUT,AD_FACTURATION_VN,AD_LIVRAISON_VN,AD_VENTE_VN,AD_PA_CODE_IMP,
    AD_LA_CODE,AD_NOM_COMMERCIAL,AD_RUE,AD_LIEU,AD_CODE_POSTAL,AD_VILLE,AD_TELEPHONE,AD_FAX,AD_EMAIL,EN_NA_CODE,EN_OE_BLOQUE,LB_VALEUR,AD_FLAG_INT,
    AD_DATE_CRE,AD_ZL_CODE_ZONE,AD_CODE_GARANTIE,ZL_LIBELLE_ZONE,LG_CODE_TR_ASSOCIE,OP_CLE_CODE,LG_ANNU_OE,LG_OE_MOD,LG_MUT_CAF,UP_ANNU_OF,
    CLIENT.ET_TE_CODE TYPE_CLIENT,CLIENT_PROTOCOLE.ET_TE_CODE TYPE_CLIENT_PROTOCOLE,LIEU_GEOGRAPHIQUE.ET_TE_CODE TYPE_LIEU_GEOGRAPHIQUE,
    PA_CODE_ISO_3C,LG_CODE_UP,UP_LIBELLE,LG_AG_CODE,LG_STOCKEUR,LG_FACT_RETEN,AD_CODE_NOTICE FROM  CVNQTAD1 LEFT JOIN CVNQTLA1 ON  
    AD_LA_CODE = LA_CODE_ISO_2C LEFT OUTER JOIN  CVNQTID1 ON  AD_EN_CODE_PSV = ID_EN_CODE_PSV JOIN  CVNQTEN1 ON  AD_EN_CODE_PSV = EN_CODE_PSV JOIN  
    CVNQTPA1 ON  AD_PA_CODE_IMP = PA_CODE_ISO_2C JOIN  CVNQTLB ON  PA_CLE_LIBELLE = LB_CLE LEFT OUTER JOIN  CVNQTZL1 ON  AD_ZL_CODE_ZONE = ZL_CODE_ZONE 
    AND  AD_MA_CODE = ZL_MA_CODE AND  AD_PA_CODE = ZL_PA_CODE LEFT OUTER JOIN  
    CVNQTET1 CLIENT ON  EN_CODE_PSV = CLIENT.ET_EN_CODE_PSV AND  CLIENT.ET_TE_CODE =  'CL'  LEFT OUTER JOIN  CVNQTET1 CLIENT_PROTOCOLE ON  
    EN_CODE_PSV = CLIENT_PROTOCOLE.ET_EN_CODE_PSV AND  CLIENT_PROTOCOLE.ET_TE_CODE =  'CD'  LEFT OUTER JOIN  CVNQTET1 LIEU_GEOGRAPHIQUE ON 
    EN_CODE_PSV = LIEU_GEOGRAPHIQUE.ET_EN_CODE_PSV AND  LIEU_GEOGRAPHIQUE.ET_TE_CODE =  'LG'  LEFT OUTER JOIN  CVNQTLG1 ON 
    AD_EN_CODE_PSV = LG_EN_CODE_PSV AND  AD_CODE = LG_AD_CODE LEFT OUTER JOIN  CVNQTUP1 ON  LG_CODE_UP = UP_CODE LEFT OUTER JOIN 
    CVNQTAG1 ON  LG_AG_CODE = AG_CODE LEFT OUTER JOIN  CVNQTOP1 ON  LG_OPERATEUR = OP_CODE  WHERE  EN_MA_CODE = 'AC' AND  AD_PA_CODE = 'NL' AND  
    (AD_PA_CODE IS NOT NULL  AND  AD_MA_CODE IS NOT NULL  AND  AD_FACTURATION_VN IS NOT NULL  AND  AD_LIVRAISON_VN IS NOT NULL  AND  
    AD_VENTE_VN IS NOT NULL  AND  AD_PA_CODE_IMP IS NOT NULL ) AND  LB_LC_LOCALE = 'fr_FR' ORDER BY  AD_PA_CODE,AD_MA_CODE ASC  
    ELSE  DECODE (AD_ADR_DEFAUT, null, '0', AD_ADR_DEFAUT) END AS AD_ADR_DEFAUT,AD_FACTURATION_VN,AD_LIVRAISON_VN,AD_VENTE_VN,AD_PA_CODE_IMP,
    AD_LA_CODE,AD_NOM_COMMERCIAL,AD_RUE,AD_LIEU,AD_CODE_POSTAL,AD_VILLE,AD_TELEPHONE,AD_FAX,AD_EMAIL,EN_NA_CODE,EN_OE_BLOQUE,LB_VALEUR,AD_FLAG_INT,
    AD_DATE_CRE,AD_ZL_CODE_ZONE,AD_CODE_GARANTIE,ZL_LIBELLE_ZONE,LG_CODE_TR_ASSOCIE,OP_CLE_CODE,LG_ANNU_OE,LG_OE_MOD,LG_MUT_CAF,UP_ANNU_OF,
    CLIENT.ET_TE_CODE TYPE_CLIENT,CLIENT_PROTOCOLE.ET_TE_CODE TYPE_CLIENT_PROTOCOLE,LIEU_GEOGRAPHIQUE.ET_TE_CODE TYPE_LIEU_GEOGRAPHIQUE,
    PA_CODE_ISO_3C,LG_CODE_UP,UP_LIBELLE,LG_AG_CODE,LG_STOCKEUR,LG_FACT_RETEN,AD_CODE_NOTICE FROM  CVNQTAD1 LEFT JOIN CVNQTLA1 ON  
    AD_LA_CODE = LA_CODE_ISO_2C LEFT OUTER JOIN  CVNQTID1 ON  AD_EN_CODE_PSV = ID_EN_CODE_PSV JOIN  CVNQTEN1 ON  AD_EN_CODE_PSV = EN_CODE_PSV JOIN  
    CVNQTPA1 ON  AD_PA_CODE_IMP = PA_CODE_ISO_2C JOIN  CVNQTLB ON  PA_CLE_LIBELLE = LB_CLE LEFT OUTER JOIN  CVNQTZL1 ON  AD_ZL_CODE_ZONE = ZL_CODE_ZONE 
    AND  AD_MA_CODE = ZL_MA_CODE AND  AD_PA_CODE = ZL_PA_CODE LEFT OUTER JOIN  
    CVNQTET1 CLIENT ON  EN_CODE_PSV = CLIENT.ET_EN_CODE_PSV AND  CLIENT.ET_TE_CODE =  'CL'  LEFT OUTER JOIN  CVNQTET1 CLIENT_PROTOCOLE ON  
    EN_CODE_PSV = CLIENT_PROTOCOLE.ET_EN_CODE_PSV AND  CLIENT_PROTOCOLE.ET_TE_CODE =  'CD'  LEFT OUTER JOIN  CVNQTET1 LIEU_GEOGRAPHIQUE ON 
    EN_CODE_PSV = LIEU_GEOGRAPHIQUE.ET_EN_CODE_PSV AND  LIEU_GEOGRAPHIQUE.ET_TE_CODE =  'LG'  LEFT OUTER JOIN  CVNQTLG1 ON 
    AD_EN_CODE_PSV = LG_EN_CODE_PSV AND  AD_CODE = LG_AD_CODE LEFT OUTER JOIN  CVNQTUP1 ON  LG_CODE_UP = UP_CODE LEFT OUTER JOIN 
    CVNQTAG1 ON  LG_AG_CODE = AG_CODE LEFT OUTER JOIN  CVNQTOP1 ON  LG_OPERATEUR = OP_CODE  WHERE  EN_MA_CODE = 'AC' AND  AD_PA_CODE = 'NL' AND  
    (AD_PA_CODE IS NOT NULL  AND  AD_MA_CODE IS NOT NULL  AND  AD_FACTURATION_VN IS NOT NULL  AND  AD_LIVRAISON_VN IS NOT NULL  AND  
    AD_VENTE_VN IS NOT NULL  AND  AD_PA_CODE_IMP IS NOT NULL ) AND  LB_LC_LOCALE = 'fr_FR' ORDER BY  AD_PA_CODE,AD_MA_CODE ASC
```

Comment: The query is very difficult to read in its current format. Consider editing your post to add line break where appropriate. Also, add some more context.

Answer (score 3):

The case construct has to have an "end".

```
CASE 
WHEN condition1 THEN value1
WHEN condition2 THEN value2
END [column-alias]
```

So, the first few lines of your query might look more like this:

```
SELECT DISTINCT 
  AD_MA_CODE 
, AD_PA_CODE 
, AD_EN_CODE_PSV 
, AD_CODE 
, CASE 
  WHEN AD_EN_CODE_PSV = ID_EN_CODE_PSV AND AD_CODE = ID_AD_CODE 
    THEN '1' 
  WHEN AD_CODE_POSTAL=ZL_CODE_POSTAL AND AD_VILLE=ZL_VILLE 
    THEN AD_ADR_DEFAUT
  END c1
, AD_FACTURATION_VN 
. . .
```

I would also caution *against* the "blind" use of `select distinct`.
If you're getting "duplicate" rows in your query, then removing the *cause* of that duplication (often an incorrect join condition) is a better choice then trying to get the database to try and resolve them out afterwards.
This can have a *huge* negative performance impact, especially on resultsets with a large number of columns (`distinct a, b, c` can perform as poorly as `group by a, b, c order by a, b, c` - and you've a *lot* more than three columns there!).